# What can I do if my roommates poisoned me?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, liability, human-rights

What can I do if my roommates poisoned me by improperly using pesticide without asking if it was okay with me to use it or even warning me or telling me after the fact?

The product says clearly it is not to be used in areas that occupied more than 4 hours a day, rooms with vents, or anything not sealed.  I woke up very sick and with an intense headache.  This is not something that I ever experience under normal conditions.  I found an open package and rubber gloves outside of their rooms.  I heard them talking about it the night when I was in the bathroom about to take a shower, but it made more sense the following morning.  I heard our other roommate telling them that it came in the mail and didn't come with directions, so doing what "that guy" said should be fine.  I took a picture of the package, and on the label it says at the top with large letters that it is only for sale to and use by professionals.

Comment: Have you tried talking to your roommates and telling them how you feel?

Comment: Assuming you're in the US, call the hotline for the poison control center: 1 (800) 222-1222  (you can call 24 hours a day, seven days a week). If you want to take things further legally, call the cops and insist that they file out a police report (you may not win in criminal court, but may be you can sue in civil court and for that you'll need a police report even if the police is reticent to fill one out for you).

Comment: For a moment the question title made me wonder what kind of SE this was. Arqade is famous for its out of context question titles.

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking what your legal rights are? Or what? I don't see what makes this on topic for Law - right now it seems to not be asking for anything legal and is more of an interpersonal question.

Comment: @enderland Given the name of the website, I figured law-related inquiry and response was ubiquitously implied.  I don't know if what they did was actually illegal, a gray area, or whatnot.  Whether I can take legal action or not I would imagine would first require knowing whether what they did was illegal, independently and/or with respect to my rights.  I did not anticipate anyone questioning whether I am looking for legal insight, even particularly regarding my rights, when I have a 'rights' tag.  Are my presumptions naive and/or absurd? Please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: @NickODell Assuming your response is genuine, please see my response to dwoz below.  (Is referring to other responses, for reducing redundancy, generally seen as a good thing on this forum?)

Comment: I thought at first it was similar to [this poisoning case](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3023221/Stanford-PhD-cancer-researcher-caught-poisoning-classmates-water-bottles-carcinogen-paraformaldehyde.html)

Answer (score 17):

If you're concerned for your health, see a doctor and get a diagnosis.

Ask your roommates to stop the behaviour.

If you have suffered losses that you believe you should be compensated for, ask your roommates to compensate you.

If they don't stop, or they won't compensate you, *and* you think it is worth the time, money, and attention, you could talk to a lawyer regarding a negligence lawsuit. You can also move out.

Comment: If you are going to sue your roommate for negligence, there is a good chance they are not willing to live together with you anymore due to the awkwardness of the situation. Be prepared to find a new roommate if yiu go down this path.

Comment: @nomenagentis Sorry. I don't have money for the doctor or moving out.  Thank you for the negligence lawsuit suggestion.  I think this is the first useful thing I've seen (beyond the obvious layman stuff).  I am completely unfamiliar with what a negligence lawsuit is.  Is it based on money/damage or principle/intent?  The info I shared about my roommates, in response to dwoz further down, may be relevant here as well.

Comment: @user3146: so we can presume you don't have the money to pay a lawyer either. Sometimes lawyers will take a case on "contingency", where they get paid out of whatever money you get from the defendants, but I think this usually is only an option when you are suing someone with lots of money. Unless your roommates are rich, there probably isn't enough potential gain here to interest a contingency lawyer.

Answer (score -4):

It sounds like you have a very close and articulated relationship with your roomies! Retrieve the pesticide package from the hallway, put it in a plastic ziplock bag, put the ziplock bag in another plastic bag, take the whole thing to your doctor and ask them to assess what you've been exposed to.  Then take steps to heal your living situation with your roomates.

No court will accept the given description as constituting "harm."  We have a person who is exhibiting some vague symptoms, which may or may not be characteristic of exposure to an unknown substance.  The temporal coincidence of the two occurring together is not proof of anything, though it might be, if a medical professional determined it to be so...thus the very first step is to **document the harm.**

Comment: This is needlessly rude.

Comment: I'm sure his roommates had some sort of responsibility to at least tell him about the poison. No need to get snappy. You're *not* psychic, so unless you know the asker personally, you are simply jumping to conclusions.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with law?

Comment: First, roomates that don't inform another roommate when they're using poison to delouse an apartment are by definition not in a healthy relationship with that roommate...and when the excluded roommate's first impulse is to evaluate legal remedies, that only confirms it.  The tone was too snarky, granted.  The connection with the law is that she has not evinced any information that establishes harm, beyond her hurt feelings.  She has to substantiate and document whether actual harm haas occurred before hitting the torts train.

Comment: @dwoz As Hugo Zink already tried to bring your attention to, you are again jumping to conclusions. It was not a first impulse. I am only now starting to doubt two other roommates. The one I overheard giving the other two absurd instructions, is the one that all everyone has insisted is the problem. There is a small possibility that the 'problem roommate' did it "for" them, and that they are as violated as I am. So before I start a conversation wherein I may be outnumbered and my intentions of resorting to authorities may come up, I want to be prepared and not cause them to remove the evidence.

Comment: @HugoZink Is there any sort of legal implication regarding responsibilities with poison that you are aware of?

Comment: @dwoz Though the assumptions aren't helpful, maybe editing/elaborating the sorts of things that constitute harm could encourage some up-voting.  (I didn't down-vote it, for whatever that's worth.)

Answer (score -4):

So, I have the first step in answering the question covered.

http://www.ocvcd.org/docs/Labels_MSDS/NUVAN_PROSTRIPS_MSDS.pdf

> It is a violation of Federal Law to use this product in any manner
>   inconsistent with its labeling.

http://www.amvac-chemical.com/products/documents/Nuvan%20Prostrips%20Plus%20Specimen%20Label.12679-20150305.pdf

> For use in unoccupied areas; not for use in homes except garages, attics, crawl spaces, and sheds occupied  by people for less than 4 hours per day.  Also for use in boathouses, museum collections, animal  buildings, reptile houses, motor control rooms, and  milk rooms, or  enclosed areas thereof, occupied by people for less than 4 hours per  day.  Also for use in the following unoccupied structures,  provided  they are unoccupied for more than 4 months  immediately following  placement of a pest strip: vacation homes, cabins, mobile homes,  boats, farm houses,  and ranch houses.

So, one option is to inform them of this.  Then they will understand (even if they care about no other consequences) they are tinkering with federal law. And, if they continue, pursue information on how to take legal action on the federal level.  Otherwise, take note of the following sources regarding long term and delayed effects, and, if any medical concerns consistent with the literature continues/arises, then pursue medical funds (first by asking personally, then by lawsuit if necessary).

http://pmep.cce.cornell.edu/profiles/extoxnet/carbaryl-dicrotophos/dichlorvos-ext.html

> Some organophosphates may cause delayed symptoms beginning 1 to 4
>   weeks after an acute exposure which may or may not have produced
>   immediate symptoms. In such cases, numbness, tingling, weakness and
>   cramping may appear in the lower limbs and progress to incoordination
>   and paralysis. Improvement may occur over months or years, but some
>   residual impairment will remain (9).

http://nj.gov/health/eoh/rtkweb/documents/fs/0674.pdf (a fact sheet for dichlorvos)

> HAZARD SUMMARY
>
> - Dichlorvos can affect you when breathed in and by  passing through your skin.
> - Dichlorvos should be handled as a CARCINOGEN-- WITH EXTREME CAUTION.
> - Exposure to  Dichlorvos can cause rapid  Organophosphate  poisoning with headache, sweating, nausea and vomiting,  diarrhea, loss of
>     coordination, and death.
> - High or repeated exposure may damage the nerves causing  weakness, "pins and needles," and poor coordination in the  arms and legs.
> - Repeated exposure may cause personality changes of  depression, anxiety or irritability
>
> Chronic Health Effects  The following chronic (long-term) health
>   effects can occur at  some time after exposure to  Dichlorvos  and can
>   last for months  or years:  Cancer Hazard 
>   *  Dichlorvos  may be a CARCINOGEN in humans since it  has been shown to cause cancer  of the pancreas in animals. 
>   *    Many scientists believe there is no safe level of exposure to  a carcinogen. Such substances may also have the potential  for causing
>   reproductive damage in humans.  Reproductive Hazard 
>   *   There is limited evidence that  Dichlorvos  is a teratogen in  animals. Until further testing has been done, it should be  treated as
>   a possible teratogen in humans.  Other Long-Term Effects 
>   *   High or repeated exposure may damage the nerves causing  weakness, "pins and needles," and poor coordination in the  arms and legs. 
>   *  Repeated exposure may cause personality changes of  depression, anxiety or irritability.
>
> QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS
>
> Q:    If I have acute health effects, will I later get chronic  health
>   effects?  A:    Not always.  Most chronic (long-term) effects result
>   from  repeated exposures to a chemical.  Q:    Can I get long-term
>   effects without ever having short- term effects?  A:    Yes, because
>   long-term e ffects can occur from repeated  exposures to a chemical at
>   levels not high enough to make  you immediately sick.  Q:    What are
>   my chances of ge tting sick when I have been  exposed to chemicals? 
>   A:   The likelihood of becoming sick from chemicals is  increased as
>   the amount of exposure increases.  This is  determined by the length
>   of time and the amount of  material to which someone is exposed.  Q:
>   When are higher exposures more likely?  A:   Conditions which increase
>   risk of exposure include  physical and mechanical processes  (heating,
>   pouring,  spraying, spills and evaporation from large surface areas 
>   such as open containers),  and "confined space" exposures (working
>   inside vats, reactors, boilers, small rooms, etc.).  Q:    Is the risk
>   of getting sick  higher for workers than for  community residents?  A:
>   Yes.  Exposures in the community, except possibly in  cases of fires
>   or spills, are usually much lower than those  found in the workplace. 
>   However, people in the  community may be exposed to contaminated water
>   as  well as to chemicals in the air over long periods.  This  may be a
>   problem for children or people who are already  ill.  Q:     Don't all
>   chemicals cause cancer?  A:    No.  Most chemicals tested  by
>   scientists are not cancer- causing.  Q:    Should I be concerned if a
>   chemical causes cancer in  animals?  A:    Yes. Most scientists agr ee
>   that a chemical that causes  cancer in animals should be treated as a
>   suspected human  carcinogen unless proven otherwise.  Q:    But don't
>   they test animals using much higher levels of a  chemical than people
>   usually are exposed to?  A:    Yes.  That's so effects can  be seen
>   more clearly using  fewer animals.  But high doses alone don't cause
>   cancer  unless it's a cancer agent.  In  fact, a chemical that causes 
>   cancer in animals at high doses could cause cancer in  humans exposed
>   to low doses.  Q:    Should I be concerned if a chemical is a
>   teratogen in  animals?  A:   Yes. Although some chemicals may affect
>   humans  differently than they affect  animals, damage to animals 
>   suggests that similar damage can occur in humans.

chemical.com/products/documents/Nuvan%20Prostrips%20Plus%20Specimen%20Label.12679-20150305.pdf

> This product contains a chemical known to the State of California to
>   cause cancer: DDVP

http://pmep.cce.cornell.edu/profiles/extoxnet/carbaryl-dicrotophos/dichlorvos-ext.html

#### Long term

> Repeated or prolonged exposure to organophosphates may result in the
>   same effects as acute exposure including the delayed symptoms. Other
>   effects reported in workers repeatedly exposed include impaired memory
>   and concentration, disorientation, severe depressions, irritability,
>   confusion, headache, speech difficulties, delayed reaction times,
>   nightmares, sleepwalking and drowsiness or insomnia. An influenza-like
>   condition with headache, nausea, weakness, loss of appetite, and
>   malaise has also been reported (9).

#### Delayed

> Some organophosphates may cause delayed symptoms beginning 1 to 4
>   weeks after an acute exposure which may or may not have produced
>   immediate symptoms. In such cases, numbness, tingling, weakness and
>   cramping may appear in the lower limbs and progress to incoordination
>   and paralysis. Improvement may occur over months or years, but some
>   residual impairment will remain (9).

#### Short term

> Acute illness from dichlorvos is limited to the effects of
>   cholinesterase inhibition. Compared to poisoning by other
>   organophosphates, dichlorvos causes a more rapid onset of symptoms,
>   which is often followed by a similarly rapid recovery (3). This occurs
>   because dichlorvos is rapidly metabolized and eliminated from the
>   body. Persons with reduced pulmonary (lung) function, convulsive
>   disorders, liver disorders, or recent exposure to cholinesterase
>   inhibitors will be at increased risk from exposure to dichlorvos.
>   Alcoholic beverages may enhance the toxic effects of dichlorvos. High
>   environmental temperatures or exposure of dichlorvos to visible or UV
>   light may enhance its toxicity (9).
>
> Dichlorvos is highly toxic by inhalation, dermal absorption and
>   ingestion (9). Because dichlorvos is volatile, inhalation is the most
>   common route of exposure. As with all organophosphates, dichlorvos is
>   readily absorbed through the skin. Skin which has come in contact with
>   this material should be washed immediately with soap and water and all
>   contaminated clothing should be removed.
>
> Dichlorvos is mildly irritating to skin (9). Concentrates of
>   dichlorvos may cause burning sensations, or actual burns (6).
>   Dichlorvos can be very toxic if it is not immediately washed off, but
>   instead left on the skin long enough for it to become absorbed through
>   the skin and into the bloodstream. One man nearly died after spilling
>   4 ounces of a 3% oil solution of dichlorvos on his lap. He did not
>   wash it off. Another man only became nauseous and dizzy after spilling
>   a similar amount on his arm. He washed off the dichlorvos with soap
>   and water (6). Do not use organic solvents to remove dichlorvos from
>   the skin (DLA/DOD Hazardous Mat'ls Info. System #0014-29- 438-0000.
>   1982).
>
> The organophosphate insecticides are cholinesterase inhibitors. They
>   are highly toxic by all routes of exposure. When inhaled, the first
>   effects are usually respiratory and may include bloody or runny nose,
>   coughing, chest discomfort, difficult or short breath, and wheezing
>   due to constriction or excess fluid in the bronchial tubes. Skin
>   contact with organophosphates may cause localized sweating and
>   involuntary muscle contractions. Eye contact will cause pain,
>   bleeding, tears, pupil constriction, and blurred vision. Following
>   exposure by any route, other systemic effects may begin within a few
>   minutes or be delayed for up to 12 hours. These may include pallor,
>   nausea, vomiting, diarrhea, abdominal cramps, headache, dizziness, eye
>   pain, blurred vision, constriction or dilation of the eye pupils,
>   tears, salivation, sweating, and confusion. Severe poisoning will
>   affect the central nervous system, producing incoordination, slurred
>   speech, loss of reflexes, weakness, fatigue, involuntary muscle
>   contractions, twitching, tremors of the tongue or eyelids, and
>   eventually paralysis of the body extremities and the respiratory
>   muscles. In severe cases there may also be involuntary defecation or
>   urination, psychosis, irregular heart beats, unconsciousness,
>   convulsions and coma. Death may be caused by respiratory failure or
>   cardiac arrest (9).
>
> Dichlorvos is very volatile, meaning that it readily forms vapors
>   which may be inhaled. Inhalation is the most common way to be exposed
>   to dichlorvos. Low, repeated doses may be non-toxic. High doses of
>   dichlorvos may be very toxic, especially if inhalation exposure is
>   continuous (6). Dichlorvos produces irritating gases, such as
>   phosphorous and chlorine oxides, when heated (NIH/EPA 1984).
>
> Eye protection should be worn when handling dichlorvos. Application of
>   1.67 mg/kg in rabbits' eyes produced mild redness and swelling, but no injury to the cornea (9). Dichlorvos may cause eye burns.
>   Organophosphates cause the pupils to constrict (pin point pupils).

http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/9737/1/IJEB%2048%287%29%20697-709.pdf
This one is a pretty resourceful and concise review.

> In fact, acute sub lethal  doses of OPs were shown to have long-term
>   effects in  humans 28,29. 28 Ohbu  S,  Yamashina  A,  Takasu  N  & 
>   Yamaguchi  T,  Sarin  poisoning on Tokyo subway,  South Med,  90
>   (1997) 587.  29 Proctor  S P,  Heaton  K  J,  Heeren  T  &  White  R 
>   F,  Effe cts  of  sarin  and  cyclosarin  exposure  during  the  1991 
>   Gulf  War  on  neurobehavioral     functioning     in     US     army 
>   veterans,  Neurotoxicology,  27 (2006) 931.
>   (Organophosphates, e.g. dichlorvos, and other pesticides are also chemical warfare weapons.)

Also, regarding medical testing:

http://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/phs/phs.asp?id=595&tid=111

> 1.6 Is there a medical test to show whether I've been exposed to dichlorvos?
>
> Two blood tests exist that can determine whether you have been exposed
>   to significant levels of dichlorvos. These tests can be performed by
>   any hospital or clinical laboratory. These tests measure the activity
>   of two enzymes (called serum cholinesterase and erythrocyte [red blood
>   cell] acetylcholinesterase) that are affected by dichlorvos.
>   Dichlorvos affects these enzymes at lower levels of exposure than
>   necessary to produce harmful effects. This means that if these enzymes
>   have been affected, you will not necessarily have effects on your
>   health. Many other insecticides also affect these enzymes. To
>   determine whether you have been specifically exposed to dichlorvos, a
>   laboratory test must measure the breakdown products in your urine.
>   Tests of this type are not routinely done in hospital laboratories and
>   your doctor will have to send a sample to a specialized laboratory.

If you looking at this immediately after exposure:

http://toxnet.nlm.nih.gov/cgi-bin/sis/search/a?dbs+hsdb:@term+@DOCNO+319
This webpage has a much broader and longer wealth of info and sources.

> E)  WITH POISONING/EXPOSURE
>         1)  MILD TO MODERATE POISONING: MUSCARINIC EFFECTS: Can
>             include bradycardia, salivation, lacrimation,
>             diaphoresis, vomiting, diarrhea, urination, and
>             miosis. NICOTINIC EFFECTS: Tachycardia, hypertension,
>             mydriasis, and muscle cramps.
>         2)  SEVERE POISONING: MUSCARINIC EFFECTS: Bronchorrhea,
>             bronchospasm, and acute lung injury. NICOTINIC
>             EFFECTS: Muscle fasciculations, weakness, and
>             respiratory failure. CENTRAL EFFECTS: CNS depression,
>             agitation, confusion, delirium, coma, and seizures.
>             Hypotension, ventricular dysrhythmias, metabolic
>             acidosis, pancreatitis, and hyperglycemia can also
>             develop.
>         3)  DELAYED EFFECTS: Intermediate syndrome is
>             characterized by paralysis of respiratory, cranial
>             motor, neck flexor, and proximal limb muscles 1 to 4
>             days after apparent recovery from cholinergic
>             toxicity, and prior to the development of delayed
>             peripheral neuropathy. Manifestations can include the
>             inability to lift the neck or sit up,
>             ophthalmoparesis, slow eye movements, facial weakness,
>             difficulty swallowing, limb weakness (primarily
>             proximal), areflexia, and respiratory paralysis.
>             Recovery begins 5 to 15 days after onset. Distal
>             sensory-motor polyneuropathy has been reported in a
>             small number of patients following intentional or
>             inadvertent exposure to dichlorvos. It may rarely
>             develop 6 to 21 days following exposure. Characterized
>             by burning or tingling followed by weakness beginning
>             in the legs which then spreads proximally. In severe
>             cases, it may result in spasticity or flaccidity.
>             Recovery requires months and may not be complete.
>         4)  CHILDREN: May have different predominant signs and
>             symptoms than adults (more likely CNS depression,
>             stupor, coma, flaccidity, dyspnea, and seizures).
>             Children may also have fewer muscarinic and nicotinic
>             signs of intoxication (i.e., secretions, bradycardia,
>             fasciculations and miosis) as compared to adults.
>         5)  INHALATION EXPOSURE: Organophosphate vapors rapidly
>             produce mucous membrane and upper airway irritation
>             and bronchospasm, followed by systemic muscarinic,
>             nicotinic and central effects if exposed to
>             significant concentrations. Treatment Overview:
>
> 0.4.2 ORAL EXPOSURE
>       A)  MANAGEMENT OF MILD TOXICITY
>        1)  A patient who is either asymptomatic or presents with
>            mild clinical symptoms (i.e. normal vitals, pulse
>            oximetry and an acetylcholinesterase greater than 80%
>            of lower reference range), and remains stable for 12
>            hours can be discharged. Obtain appropriate psychiatric
>            evaluation if an intentional exposure.
>       B)  MANAGEMENT OF MODERATE TO SEVERE TOXICITY
>        1)  Immediate assessment and evaluation. Airway management
>            is likely to be necessary. Simple decontamination (i.e.
>            skin and gastrointestinal, removal of contaminated
>            clothes). Administer antidotes: atropine for muscarinic
>            manifestations (e.g. salivation, diarrhea,
>            bronchorrhea), pralidoxime for nicotinic manifestations
>            (e.g. weakness, fasciculations). Treat seizures with
>            benzodiazepines. Admit to intensive care with
>            continuous monitoring, titration of antidotes,
>            ventilation, and inotropes as needed. Consult a medical
>            toxicologist and/or poison center.
>       C)  DECONTAMINATION
>        1)  PREHOSPITAL: Activated charcoal is contraindicated
>            because of possible respiratory depression and seizures
>            and risk of aspiration. Remove contaminated clothing,
>            wash skin with soap and water. Universal precautions
>            and nitrile gloves to protect personnel.
>        2)  INGESTION: Activated charcoal for large ingestions.
>            Consider nasogastric tube for aspiration of gastric
>            contents, or gastric lavage for recent large
>            ingestions, if patient is intubated or able to protect
>            airway.
>        3)  DERMAL: Remove contaminated clothing. Wash skin
>            thoroughly with soap and water. Universal precautions
>            and nitrile gloves to protect staff from contamination.
>            Systemic toxicity can result from dermal exposure.
>        4)  OCULAR: Copious eye irrigation.
>       D)  AIRWAY MANAGEMENT
>        1)  Immediately assess airway and respiratory function.
>            Administer oxygen. Suction secretions. Endotracheal
>            intubation may be necessary because of respiratory
>            muscle weakness or bronchorrhea. Avoid succinylcholine
>            for rapid sequence intubation as prolonged paralysis
>            may result. Monitoring pulmonary function (FVC, FEV1,
>            NIF) may help anticipate need for intubation.
>       E)  ANTIDOTES
>
> I)  PATIENT DISPOSITION
>        1)  HOME CRITERIA: Patients with unintentional trivial
>            exposures who are asymptomatic can be observed in the
>            home or in the workplace.
>        2)  OBSERVATION CRITERIA: Patients with deliberate or
>            significant exposure and those who are symptomatic
>            should be sent to a health care facility for
>            evaluation, treatment and observation for 6 to 12
>            hours. Onset of toxicity is variable; most patients
>            will develop symptoms within 6 hours. Patients that
>            remain asymptomatic 12 hours after an ingestion or a
>            dermal exposure are unlikely to develop severe
>            toxicity. However, highly lipophilic agents (eg;
>            fenthion) can produce initially subtle effects followed
>            by progressive weakness including respiratory failure.
>            Cholinesterase activity should be determined to confirm
>            the degree of exposure.
>        3)  ADMISSION CRITERIA: All intentional ingestions should
>            be initially managed as a severe exposure. Determine
>            cholinesterase activity to assess if a significant
>            exposure occurred. Patients who develop signs or
>            symptoms of cholinergic toxicity (e.g. muscarinic,
>            nicotinic OR central) should be admitted to an
>            intensive care setting.
>        4)  CONSULT CRITERIA: Consult a medical toxicologist and/or
>            poison center for assistance with any patient with
>            moderate to severe cholinergic manifestations.
>       J)  PITFALLS
>        1)  Inadequate initial atropinization. Patients with severe
>            toxicity require rapid administration of large doses,
>            titrate to the endpoint or drying pulmonary secretions.
>        2)  Monitor respiratory function closely, pulmonary
>            function testing may provide early clues to the
>            development of respiratory failure.
>        3)  Some component of dermal exposure occurs with most
>            significant overdoses, inadequate decontamination may
>            worsen toxicity.
>        4)  Patients should be monitored closely for 48 hours after
>            discontinuation of atropine and pralidoxime for
>            evidence of recurrent toxicity or intermediate
>            syndrome.
>       K)  TOXICOKINETICS
>        1)  Well absorbed across the lung, mucous membranes
>            (including gut), and skin; significant toxicity has
>            been reported after all these routes of exposure.
>        2)  Most patients who develop severe toxicity have signs
>            and symptoms within 6 hours of exposure, onset of
>            toxicity is rarely more than 12 hours after exposure.
>            Highly lipophilic organophosphates (e.g. fenthion,
>            disulfoton) may produce subtle early toxicity that can
>            progress to severe weakness/respiratory failure over
>            many hours.
>        3)  Recurrence of toxicity after apparent improvement has
>            been described.
>        4)  Some organophosphates undergo "ageing", a process by
>            which the bond of the organophosphate to
>            acetylcholinesterase becomes stronger, and cannot be
>            reversed readily by oximes. Early oxime administration
>            may prevent aging and shorten clinical manifestations
>            of toxicity.
>       L)  PREDISPOSING CONDITIONS
>        1)  Patients with chronic occupational exposure to
>            organophosphates may have chronically depressed
>            cholinesterase activity and may develop severe toxicity
>            after smaller acute exposures.
>        2)  Dermal absorption is enhanced in young children due to
>            larger surface area to volume ratio and more permeable
>            skin.
>       M)  DIFFERENTIAL DIAGNOSIS
>        1)  Gastroenteritis, food poisoning, asthma, myasthenic
>            crisis, cholinergic excess from medications.
>     0.4.3 INHALATION EXPOSURE
>       A)  Remove from exposure and administer oxygen if
>           respiratory distress develops.
>       B)  Inhaled ipratropium or glycopyrrolate may be useful in
>           addition to intravenous atropine for bronchorrhea and
>           bronchospasm. Inhaled beta agonists may be useful for
>           bronchospasm unresponsive to anticholinergics.
>     0.4.4 EYE EXPOSURE
>       A)  Irrigate exposed eyes with water or normal saline.
>           Systemic toxicity is unlikely to develop from ocular
>           exposure alone.
>     0.4.5 DERMAL EXPOSURE
>       A)  OVERVIEW
>        1)  Systemic effects can occur from dermal exposure to
>            organophosphates. Remove contaminated clothing, wash
>            skin thoroughly with soap and water. Use universal
>            precautions and nitrile gloves to protect staff from
>            contamination.
>        2)  Monitor for the development of cholinergic toxicity and
>            treat as in oral exposure.
>
> Range of Toxicity:
>
> A)  A toxic dose has not been established. INGESTION: The
>          probable lethal dose of dichlorvos in humans is between
>          50 and 500 mg/kg orally. INHALATION: Lowest lethal
>          inhalation dose of dichlorvos is 1 mg/m(3) in humans.    B)  Organophosphates are absorbed across the lung, mucous
>          membranes (including gut), and skin. Poisoning depends
>          upon inherent toxicity, dosage, rate of absorption, rate
>          of metabolic breakdown, and prior exposure to other
>          cholinesterase inhibitors.    C)  The World Health Organization (WHO) has classified
>          dichlorvos, technical grade, as pesticide class 1B
>          (highly hazardous).

And regarding legitimacy of the "safe levels", AMVAC (manufacturer of Nuvan, dichlorvos in general, and a host of other old high risk less reputable pesticides they bought from other manufacturers that no longer wanted to be associated with products typically after major public health related research findings, public harm, or scandals) has had a good deal to do with research that sets these numbers.  I have a bunch of bookmarked pages on this that I'll post links about their relevant shady history when I come back to this.  Here's one small example in the meanwhile:

http://www.jmedcbr.org/archives/CBMTSIII/cbmts3-5.pdf

> EPA has estimated a reference dose (RfD) of 0.0005 mg/kg-day for DV based on the study reporting decreased  rat brain
>   cholinesterase activity; NOAEL of 0.05 mg/m3 base d on the estimated
>   inhalation dose (Blair et al. 1976,  AMVAC, 1990). Based on a
>   comprehensive review of the database, the overall in the RfD was rated
>   as medium  (EPA, 1993). Published LOAEL (oral) dose of 0.1 mg/kg-day
>   for DV is 200 times the RfD (0.0005 mg/kg-day).  Derivation of RfD
>   value was based on the strengths and wea kness in the principal study
>   identified for this purpose  (Blair et al 1976; AMVAC 1990).

I have a ton more links somewhat organized.  Please feel free to inquire.

Comment: I am not completely sure what I can do from here.  I don't want to try to put them in federal prison.  But knowing I can be more certain that they won't insist on denying the severity of their actions is helpful (since it is probably pretty difficult worming around a federal crime with logical fallacies and other petty, childish antics). Is there such a thing as a federal misdemeanor?

Comment: Violation of law != commission of a crime.

Comment: @nomenagentis Yeah.. I understand at least one way this would be a concern.  Can you please let me know the possible consequence(s) you're concerned about?

Comment: @nomenagentis Also, I don't want to just throw this around as a first option, though I'm fairly uncertain of how else to go about it.  I want the one roommate to quit doing things like this (which he has done plenty of), and the same for the other two as long as he didn't actually take it upon himself to do it "for" them.  The one certainly hasn't taken me (or anyone else) seriously, and for the others, even one time for this disregard of such a health risk, they need a wake up call or something to make them take this sort of negligent behavior seriously.

Comment: @jimsug Just made a pretty huge edit.  I can see it getting very upvoted or downvoted.  I had a hard time condensing it.  I'm not actually sure if size vs content, or size at all, is a concern on this site.

Comment: @feetwet Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's your choice whether or not you want to condense it. The structure and relevance of your content is possibly more important than length - it just looks like a dump of information relating to this particular chemical with no guidance as to the legal significance of this information.